# Clarification regarding conceptual doubts

Tags: discussion, scope, homework-and-exercises

According to one of the answers to my post:

> Physics.SE is not a homework help site, it is not meant to be a resource to teach people physics, and it is not a resource intended to help right conceptual misconceptions in students. When it was originally created, this site was meant to be a place where active physicists doing active research could come and ask/answer questions. It was intended to be a resource for physicists to be able to find answers to common questions they may want to ask. Much like how SO is most useful to programmers that are trying to program.

So that means we need another site (newly from Area 51) or any other existing site?

So that really means we need or I need a different place as a student to help me get my doubts cleared?

**Edit:**
According to the anawers I am thinking that probably one these two would be then useful for me (I'm following both). I hope people will help these, as they still are in definiton `:(` :

> [image: Physics homework questions Q&A]
>   [image: Competitive Exams]

Comment: I feel your frustration @ADG. I'm primarily an SO user, and SO is simultaneously useful for students and professionals alike without any major issues. Maybe professional physicists might tend to be more condescending towards students (in general), where professional programmers might be more empathetic? An interesting thought on the variance in sociology between different industries.

Comment: Well, yes, it means you should go somewhere else for homework-like problems. I'm not sure what you want to discuss about that, but [here's](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/391/50583) a meta post about alternative sites where you potentially could ask such questions.

Comment: Original post here: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6693/

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have made a proposal for a site on Area 51 can Phy.SE help promote it?

Comment: @ADG I'm having trouble figuring out which proposal you submitted. Are you talking about the competitive exam proposal?

Comment: @Giffyguy yes, that one (don't go by it's name BTW)

Comment: @ADG I notice that there is a comment stating "These questions with attempts at understanding included would certainly be on topic at places like Physics.SE, Chemistry.SE etc." I find this to be the best answer I could muster. The idea here is, if you don't call attention to the fact that this is homework, demonstrate clearly the effort you have already put into finding the answer, and then ask a clear an concise question that can be answered definitively, the Physics.SE Q/A forum should be able to provide a constructive answer.

Comment: @Giffyguy I have tried some questions with full effort some without any conceptual beginning but none of them could prevent from being closed.

Comment: @ADG :( That's a shame. I feel like that's not what StackExchange is supposed to stand for. I'd say, reply to the post I quoted, and let them know that it's not working. I think this may be a systemic problem within the Physics community.

Comment: @Giffyguy i can't understand your comment. simple english please (english as an foreign language)

Comment: @Giffyguy anyways in my question post itself said is " it is not meant to be a resource to teach people physics, and it is not a resource intended to help right conceptual misconceptions in students"

Comment: If you are using area51, then individual Stack Exchange users are the people you need to reach. And their interest will be a personal matter. Things you can do: mention it here; mention it in chat (but don't get spammy about it, please); create a [on-site add](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6388/520) for the proposal and collect enough votes that it starts showing up on the main site.

Comment: @Giffyguy I admit it has been a couple of years since I was really active on Stack Overflow, but while I was it was clearly a site for *programmers* and not for people just learning to program. It works fine for students once they can frame their questions in a programmer-like way and didn't ask for (a) their homework to be done for them or (b) something for which they should have Read The Furnished Manual. In other words the rules there are (or perhaps were, as I said I have not been active much recently) more like those on Physics SE than Math SE.

Comment: @dmckee That makes sense. Thanks for the added perspective.

Comment: @ADG See [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/6739/8563) and [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/915/). Whether people upvote it and go and support your proposal is up to them, and to how attractive you can make the proposed site. How are you planning to attract experts?

Comment: Yay, I was quoted! I'm making a difference!

Comment: @ADG this metaquestion might be interesting for you to look at http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/examples-of-good-homework-questions

Comment: @dmckee - "Furnished". So THAT is what the F in RTFM stands for. I had it wrong all these years!

Comment: I won't be supporting sites where students attempt to cheat by getting their homework questions (which may well be assessed for the purposes of degree classification) answered by someone else. If any of my students get caught using such sites to answer assessed problems they will be charged with serious academic misconduct.

Comment: @RobJeffries what if he has tried his all best and shown the site all his efforts? there's no harm in guiding him to move ahead or helping him clarify his conceptual mistake so that he may be able to solve such questions. And of homework, I do not use such tags, I am just preparing for some entrance examination (IITJEE, one of the hardest examinations, if you've heard) and I just need help with my wrong concepts or some problems that I have tried my level best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, we are not a homework help site; there are other venues for that (see [My question was closed on Phys.SE. Can you recommend me another internet site where my question might be on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh) for more details), if that is what you really need/want.

At the SE level, each SE site has their own self-given rules about what is on-topic and what is off-topic. While [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com) and [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) might approve of doing someone else's homework, we don't. And we're not really interested in opening the flood gates for that, as [you can read in the many posts here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework+is%3Aquestion).

If you *do* want some physics homework help on SE "turf," there is an area51 proposal already active to this end:

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77677/physics-homework-questions

It has a long way to go (40 Q's with >9 score and 42 more people following it), but it *could* happen *if it gathers momentum*. This could only happen if people who *want it* will go out and *promote it*.

> So that really means we need or I need a different place as a student to help me get my doubts cleared?

If your doubts are numerically based (e.g., *I entered "this" into my equation and got the wrong answer! Help me!*) then yes. If your doubts are conceptually based (e.g., *How can quasars emit anything if they are black holes?*<sup>1</sup>), then you are at the correct spot.

Note that many (but likely not all) of the numerically based questions *could* be turned into a decent conceptual question, *if* (big stress there) the OP takes the time to think about *what* is troubling them.

<sup>1 Asked and answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137837/)</sup>