# What's wrong with my post?

Tags: support, specific-question

I posted this

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303764/95563

And it was put on hold, then I added more info and explained that this is my attempt to a solution, but I got no answer and it's still on hold?

Comment: FYI, there are sites such as http://www.onlineocr.net. that does a  very good job with images of text to produce regular text ,  of course math will still be a problem

Answer (score 5):

The most obvious thing that's wrong with it is that you have posted an image of typeable text. Don't do that. You can use images for diagrams, but when it comes to things you can type, you should instead transcribe them into a post and put them in a quote block. You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for math rendering.

The next thing, and the reason it was put on hold, is that you're not asking a conceptual question. Actually, you don't really *ask* anything, but the closest you come to stating a problem is when you say that you're not getting the right answer. That's not the sort of thing we handle. What we're looking for here are questions about procedures, like whether a particular formula is applicable to a particular situation, or how to choose the value of a certain variable, or whether you need to account for a certain force, or so on. So think about your question and identify what exactly it is that's holding you back from finding the solution. If you can't come up with anything other than that you're not getting the right answer, [this is not the place](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh) to ask your question. But if you are having a conceptual difficulty, like the examples I mentioned earlier, you can probably ask that here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!