# Moderator deleted my answer

Tags: discussion

Moderator [Rob](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/44126/rob) deleted my answer for the question [Pendulum in a lift](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/470940/137269) with the comment

> Hi, welcome to Physics! We aren't a homework help site, so I have temporarily deleted this complete answer to a homework-like question. – rob♦

I think that it is - in this case - counter-productive. OP completely solved their problem but because a logical mistake near the end of their solution they obtained a wrong result. *They didn't ask for the correct result, they knew it.*

Other answerer gives them a complete solution, by the OP were not satisfied with it (they didn't upvote that correct answer and in the comment they insist to know, where they made a mistake). *They refuse other, simpler and correct solution(s), they only want to know their mistake.*

My answer seems as a complete solution, but it only analyzed and approved individual steps, while didn't encounter and pinpointed the place with the error. Of course, it resulted to the correct result, already known to OP. *It only repeated the OP's steps, givig them nothing new.*

As I said, my answer was temporary deleted. I didn't know, what does it mean "temporary".

The question itself was putting on hold, which is pitty, in my humble opinion, because:

*OP don't want to solve their homework for them. They wanted learn from their mistakes.*

Comment: "Homework-like" questions encompass not only "solve this exercise for me" questions but also [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583).

Comment: Also related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10128/44126

Comment: My and John Rennie's answers to [Are partial answers to homework questions allowed?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11175/are-partial-answers-to-homework-questions-allowed) also apply here.

Answer (score 4):

I support the deletion.

Nevermind the fact that "check-my-work" questions are frowned upon, this is just a screenshot rather than a fully typeset question, something [we also discourage](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/discouraging-screenshots-of-questions-at-least-the-textual-part).  Finally, the OP did not ask for clarification on a concept - like why is the tension doubled or halved, but explicitly asked for worked to be checked, essentially farming out the completion of an assignment to the community.

The current consensus is that people do not want to encourage this kind of question presented in this kind of format: it helps very few people beyond the OP.  Removing answers to such questions is in line with this consensus.