# Which criteria rule in Physics?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I admit I'm a little frustrated. Long ago I asked questions from physics that I didn't know the answer to, and these questions were ignored. Now I know a lot of answers. So I asked questions and gave them answers showing that the questions made sense and were correct.

Example: *[How to calculate the internal angular acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/500625/)*

Despite this, questions and answers are considered undesirable without giving a reason or proof of erroneous claims. What is the difference between such conduct and [the Inquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inquisition)? Is anyone else interested in the truth?

Comment: Regardless of whether you provide an answer with the question, the question needs to stand on its own. If the question text isn't clear to others, then it will be closed as Unclear What You're Asking, regardless of how clear it was in your mind, and regardless of any answers. The same goes for the other closure reasons.

Comment: In regards to the linked question, I voted to close it because it didn't actually ask a question and seemed to require my watching some YouTube video (which shouldn't be a requirement for any Q&A, posts should be entirely self-contained)

Comment: Questions need to be on-topic as well as clear. Your [first question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/464106/how-the-centripetal-forces-work-on-a-point-in-a-rigid-body) was an off-topic homework-style question. Please do not post more like this.

Comment: If you're actually asking about an [automatic question ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/280545), keep in mind that [your closed and deleted questions and answers also count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290545/280545) when evaluating your participation. You appear to prefer to delete and re-post questions and answers rather than trying to edit them into shape; the system penalizes users who post this way.

Comment: what exactly is the question in the link you refer to?  The "question" as written basically a placeholder so you can insert your answer.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Consequence of changing the moment of inertia is changed angular velocity vector. And this is angular acceleration. I asked how to calculate this angular acceleration and I gave the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to answer your question by highlighting something you wrote [in a comment](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11423/which-criteria-rule-in-physics#comment46406_12428):

> I don't need "good relevant advice", I need answers and verification of my calculations :)

If you want answers and verification of calculations, we're not the right community for you.  We're in the business of providing relevant advice.  If you start exploring [this meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/), you'll find *years* of discussion on the topic.

Some starting points:

- [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/44126)
- [Should any check-my-work questions be made on topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/44126)
- [My question was closed on Phys.SE. Can you recommend me another internet site where my question might be on-topic?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/44126)

Comment: "Physic Stack Exchange" obliges for discussion and exchange of ideas in the field of Physics. If you don't want to discuss it, change the name because you don't deserve the name which you have. You use words as meaningless propaganda but words should have value.

Comment: We're not a discussion forum; we're a question-and-answer community.

Comment: "we're a question-and-answer community." I asked the question and gave the answer, which means I used your portal correctly. You sort the questions into those that you like and those that are not correct (those you don't know the answer). This behavior has nothing to do with Physics.

Comment: @SylwesterL We're a question and answer community with specific guidelines (made mostly _by_ community discussion).  It's not as straightforward as "any questions and answers related to physics are on topic".  You need to stop asserting that people are closing things because they don't know the answer.  I would say a majority of the questions closed here, people know the answers, they just don't fit on the site and _shouldn't_ be answered here.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the criteria that “rule” here are:

Be [on-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
Be clear.
Be correct (when answering).
Be concise.
Be interesting.
Use proper English.
Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
Don’t use images of text or equations.
Don’t ask a question that can be answered with a quick search of the web or of this site.

There is no requirement that downvoters explain why they have downvoted. Lots of us experience “Why did I get downvoted?” (I certainly have) and it can be painful. Some people will tell you why but others won’t give you any feedback. It is *your* job to learn how to ask good questions, not other people’s job (at least not *here*) to teach you.

Answer (score -7):

Because the majority of dictatorship will kick my questions out, then let me answer my question again.

Current criteria rule are:

-compliance with books. Something that doesn't match the book must be wrong, currently this is proof of falsity.

-Written in the correct English. Someone who doesn't speak this language can't be right.

-It depends on what the sponsor is behind you. Someone who has no back is nobody.

The truth is not important. Arguments, calculations, mathematical evidence now are rubbish.

Comment: When you posted this question, what was your goal? Was it a genuine interest in the answer? Or were you just looking to rant and lash out at a community that keeps certain quality standards because they're asking you to match the same criteria as everyone else? (hint: only one of those two is appropriate.)

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty My goal is looking for answers to my questions. The problem is that for many these questions are uncomfortable because they should know the answers but do not know them. Instead of seeking answers, they prefer to burn them at the stake and pretend they aren't there. Contemporary Inquisition.

Comment: @SylwesterL ... no.  You need to stop acting like you _know_ why users chose to close your questions, even when it goes against everything that the users are telling you.  You're _assuming_ that the questions are being closed because people don't know the answers, but there is no evidence of that.  You've been given plenty of good relevant advice in the comments about what you should work on improving to get questions well received here.  If you keep assuming that  it's for other reasons, you're going to have a bad time here.

Comment: @JMac I don't need "good relevant advice", I need answers and verification of my calculations:)

Comment: @SylwesterL If you want to get the answers and verification of your calculations _on this site_, you absolutely **do** need good relevant advice, because your responses (and this answer) show that you seem to be misunderstanding how the system works.

Comment: @JMac You must understand that the system which you promoting is ineffective. Using my methods, I found the answers to the questions which you couldn't answer. The answers which I found should have been found a long time ago but the current system does not allow it. Now I have a lot of answers and I have to break the system which blocks them.

Comment: @SylwesterL You're misunderstanding the conversation.  There's a difference between questions people _couldn't_ answer, and questions that _shouldn't_ be answered on this site.  People aren't answering them because they don't belong here in that format, not because they aren't able to.

Comment: @JMac I would like to ask questions as you expect but this is beyond mine possibilities. This is a standard problem for those who propose new solutions, are not understood by those who are old habits. It is impossible to introduce new solutions as not to break the old schemes. If something does not break the current schemes there is nothing new there.