# Stop closing questions that are considered "homework type"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, homework-and-exercises, close-reasons, reopen

I recently posted a question [What will be the final temperature in this case?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/748919/2451) Which contained information about a thermodynamical process and asked to calculate work done. The question was tagged "homework type" and then closed.

I deleted that one and asked again in a different version from different account. But it was closed too. Why are these people closing these questions? This type of question helps me and others clear concepts. Which concept I missed in the particular question and there could be other approaches for that question that gives new ideas.

The *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange sites don't do these types of silly things. Why do PSE does it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/)

Comment: Note that it is against our guidelines to use multiple accounts to do things that a single account cannot do. Abuse of multiple accounts can lead to the suspension of your ability to interact with the site at all.

Comment: *Mathematics* is a homework site. *Chemistry* is (much?) less so.

Answer (score 11):

In the question you link, you explicitly ask for someone to find *for you* a solution method, exactly as if this question were part of a homework and you did not know how to solve it.

The community has chosen and reaffirmed its preference to focus on conceptual questions, rather than direct help for narrow and specific questions of the type you posted.

If you need assignment help, you should read answers to [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/36194).
In particular, [quandaexchange.com](http://physics.qandaexchange.com/)  and [physicsforum.com](https://www.physicsforums.com/) are functioning perfectly well right now.